# DVD ROM keeps spining at random times

Tags: linux, debian, dvd, 32-bit, compact-disc

My dvd rom tries to read disk at random moments while I don't actually use it. I even disabled it in BIOS but no help.

How to disable dvd rom permanently? What causes this behavior?

I can't reproduce problem, It just sometimes happens.

```
$ uname -a
Linux PC 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
$ ls /media/
cdrom  cdrom0
```

Comment: Random disk spinning is usually caused by other software that is browsing through local storage media.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a disk in the drive, and it's mounted (maybe automatically mounted at boot) then anything that searches the filesystem (backup prog, indexer, antivirus - could be there even on linux) could search the drive & spin it up.

If you're not using it at all why not take out the disk? If it still makes "spin up" noises with no disk in it, I think it may have a hardware problem.

And, you could unplug the data cable to see if it still makes "spin up" noises then, that would definitely be a hardware problem. But that would only be very easy for a desktop, laptops often have both plugs together &/or the drive "plugs into" the laptop.

I haven't seen desktop dvd drives make noise except at boot, when they check for a disk, but after that they remember that they're empty and keep quiet. A laptop drive could possibly have a ***dirty door switch***, that might cause it to think it's opened and closed then powering on to look for a disk?

Comment: Drive is empty, no disk in it. It seems mounted but I got empty result of `$ lsof | grep cdrom`.
It actually don't spin but it tries to read something making that sound.
I'd like not to open my laptop.

Comment: I haven't seen dvd drives make noise except at boot, when they check for a disk, but after that they remember that they're empty... I was thinking it was a desktop, with easy to reach 2 separate wires for data & power, so probably can't unplug just one in a laptop.

Comment: Maybe it's mechanical problem with switch. But it looks ok, no way of testing this.

Comment: Cleaning/dusting it out might help? Otherwise more in-depth cleaning like taking it apart & cleaning the contacts, but that kind of cleaning sometimes breaks more than it fixes on delicate parts